Error trying to connect external db with Rails
Guys im trying to connect my application to an external database to consume it.
I configured the database.yml
I created a model to the external database.
Postgres version is: psql (PostgreSQL) 17.0
OpenSSL version is: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
Ruby version is: ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version is: Rails 7.0.8
Ubuntu version is: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
But when I try to make some consult, like:
x = ExternalDb.connection.execute("select * from PRODUTOS;")
I get the follow error:
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:690: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00007f20ec492140
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0047 p:---- s:0287 e:000286 CFUNC  :connect_poll
c:0046 p:0543 s:0283 e:000282 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:690
c:0045 p:0354 s:0270 e:000269 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:824
c:0044 p:0007 s:0259 e:000258 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:759
c:0043 p:0019 s:0253 e:000252 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg.rb:63
c:0042 p:0013 s:0247 e:000246 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_ada
c:0041 p:0112 s:0241 e:000239 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_ada [FINISH]
c:0040 p:---- s:0233 e:000232 CFUNC  :public_send
c:0039 p:0021 s:0227 e:000226 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conne
c:0038 p:0021 s:0223 e:000222 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conne
c:0037 p:0014 s:0219 e:000218 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conne
c:0036 p:0012 s:0213 e:000212 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conne
c:0035 p:0011 s:0207 e:000205 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conne
c:0034 p:0021 s:0201 e:000197 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conne
c:0033 p:0291 s:0194 e:000193 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/conne
c:0032 p:0014 s:0184 e:000183 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:313
c:0031 p:0003 s:0180 e:000179 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:280
c:0030 p:0011 s:0176 E:0006c8 EVAL   (irb):1 [FINISH]
c:0029 p:---- s:0172 e:000171 CFUNC  :eval
c:0028 p:0020 s:0164 e:000163 METHOD /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:116
c:0027 p:0059 s:0156 e:000154 METHOD /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/context.rb:450
c:0026 p:0163 s:0147 e:000146 BLOCK  /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:567
c:0025 p:0024 s:0142 e:000141 METHOD /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:751
c:0024 p:0007 s:0136 e:000135 BLOCK  /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:548
c:0023 p:0123 s:0131 e:000130 BLOCK  /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:251 [FINISH]
c:0022 p:---- s:0127 e:000126 CFUNC  :loop
c:0021 p:0005 s:0123 e:000122 BLOCK  /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233 [FINISH]
c:0020 p:---- s:0120 e:000119 CFUNC  :catch
c:0019 p:0010 s:0115 e:000114 METHOD /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232
c:0018 p:0046 s:0111 E:0009e8 METHOD /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:547
c:0017 p:0004 s:0106 e:000105 BLOCK  /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:481 [FINISH]
c:0016 p:---- s:0103 e:000102 CFUNC  :catch
c:0015 p:0058 s:0098 E:000ac0 METHOD /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:480
c:0014 p:0104 s:0092 e:000091 METHOD /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:409
c:0013 p:0173 s:0086 e:000085 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:74
c:0012 p:0009 s:0082 e:000081 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19
c:0011 p:0058 s:0077 e:000076 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:106
c:0010 p:0054 s:0073 e:000072 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:28
c:0009 p:0040 s:0065 e:000064 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127
c:0008 p:0235 s:0058 e:000057 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor.rb:527
c:0007 p:0045 s:0045 e:000044 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87
c:0006 p:0168 s:0038 e:000037 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command.rb:48
c:0005 p:0063 s:0026 e:000025 TOP    /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18 [FINISH]
c:0004 p:---- s:0021 e:000020 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0258 s:0016 e:000015 METHOD /home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
c:0002 p:0031 s:0006 e:000005 EVAL   bin/rails:4 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:001720 (none) [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:106:in `perform'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `start'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:74:in `start'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:409:in `start'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:480:in `run'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:480:in `catch'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:481:in `block in run'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:547:in `eval_input'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `each_top_level_statement'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `catch'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233:in `loop'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:251:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:548:in `block in eval_input'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:751:in `signal_status'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb.rb:567:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/context.rb:450:in `evaluate'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:116:in `evaluate'
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:116:in `eval'
(irb):1:in `<main>'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:280:in `connection'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:313:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:211:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:181:in `connection'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:341:in `checkout'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:640:in `acquire_connection'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:679:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:700:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `new_connection'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `public_send'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:78:in `new_client'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg.rb:63:in `connect'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:759:in `new'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:824:in `connect_to_hosts'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:690:in `async_connect_or_reset'
/home/rails/deploy/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg/connection.rb:690:in `connect_poll'

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 RIP: 0x00007f20ec492140 RBP: 0x0000561a0e6f4d38 RSP: 0x00007ffe5e045b68
 RAX: 0x0000000000000000 RBX: 0x00007f20ec4952c0 RCX: 0x0000000000000000
 RDX: 0x0000561a09f8e010 RDI: 0x0000561a0e6f5010 RSI: 0x0000561a0f682410
  R8: 0x0000000000000000  R9: 0x0000000000000000 R10: 0x00007f20ecc19630
 R11: 0x00007f20ecd2da10 R12: 0x0000561a0e6f4d30 R13: 0x00007f20ece44b10
 R14: 0x0000561a0e035b20 R15: 0x00007ffe5e04a530 EFL: 0x0000000000010202

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/libruby.so.3.0(rb_vm_bugreport+0x4a4) [0x7f20f101ea74]
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/libruby.so.3.0(rb_bug_for_fatal_signal+0xf4) [0x7f20f0e228b4]
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/libruby.so.3.0(sigsegv+0x4d) [0x7f20f0f73a2d]
[0x7f20f0b66520]
[0x7f20ec492140]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: bin/rails

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 thread.rb
    2 rational.so
    3 complex.so
    4 ruby2_keywords.rb
    5 /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
    6 /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
    7 /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
    8 /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    9 /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
   10 /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
   11 /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb

... more thousands lines. And finish with:
7f20f0d40000-7f20f0d4d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f20f0d4e000-7f20f0d4f000 r--p 00000000 fc:01 1054710                    /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
7f20f0d4f000-7f20f0d50000 r-xp 00001000 fc:01 1054710                    /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
7f20f0d50000-7f20f0d51000 r--p 00002000 fc:01 1054710                    /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
7f20f0d51000-7f20f0d52000 r--p 00002000 fc:01 1054710                    /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
7f20f0d52000-7f20f0d53000 rw-p 00003000 fc:01 1054710                    /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
7f20f0d53000-7f20f0d83000 r--p 00000000 fc:01 1054630                    /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/libruby.so.3.0.2
7f20f0d83000-7f20f102c000 r-xp 00030000 fc:01 1054630                    /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/libruby.so.3.0.2
7f20f102c000-7f20f1134000 r--p 002d9000 fc:01 1054630                    /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/libruby.so.3.0.2
7f20f1134000-7f20f113b000 r--p 003e0000 fc:01 1054630                    /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/libruby.so.3.0.2
7f20f113b000-7f20f113e000 rw-p 003e7000 fc:01 1054630                    /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/libruby.so.3.0.2
7f20f113e000-7f20f1151000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f20f1151000-7f20f1153000 r--p 00000000 fc:01 17248                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7f20f1153000-7f20f117d000 r-xp 00002000 fc:01 17248                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7f20f117d000-7f20f1188000 r--p 0002c000 fc:01 17248                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7f20f1189000-7f20f118b000 r--p 00037000 fc:01 17248                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7f20f118b000-7f20f118d000 rw-p 00039000 fc:01 17248                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7ffe5d850000-7ffe5e04f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffe5e06c000-7ffe5e070000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffe5e070000-7ffe5e072000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]


Aborted (core dumped)

I tried to add gssencmode: disable in database.yml and I allso tried to add export PGGSSENCMODE="disable" in .zshrc

Please add the postgres version to the question.

Based on this: https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/538 it seems to be potentially caused by some incompatibility of openssl and postgres. Some people suggested the attempts you have already tried, others reported changing openssl versions helped: https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/538#issuecomment-2023168032 and one recommended updating Postgres: https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/538#issuecomment-2248467712. All have reported success to varying degrees depending on the solution used.

I updated pg gem. and my postgres is 15. I'll try to update to 16. And also i'll try change openssl. Lets see.

I updated postgres. console: psql (PostgreSQL) 17.0 (Ubuntu 17.0-1.pgdg22.04+1) and still with same error. I'll try opensll and maybe update ruby to 3.3.5.

Guys, I still stuck on this. Any new Ideas?
